# have multiple tests with same name under different node

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit

I have two different tests that share the same data:

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(ProvideTestCases))]
public void SubtractSegmentsTests(IPolyline polyline, IPolyline toRemove, double tol, IGeometry expected)
{
    GeometryTools.SubtractSegments(polyline, toRemove, tol, null);
    AssertEqualPoints((IPointCollection) expected, (IPointCollection) polyline);
}
[TestCaseSource(nameof(ProvideTestCases))]
public void SubtractSegmentsTests_With_Esri(IPolyline polyline, IPolyline toRemove, double tol, IGeometry expected)
{
    var actual = ((ITopologicalOperator)polyline).Difference(toRemove);
    AssertEqualPoints((IPointCollection)expected, (IPointCollection)actual);
}
```

So what I want to achieve is to test two different ways, if both return the exact same results. Therefor both test-methods refer to the exact same testcases:

```
public IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ProvideTestCases()
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(...).SetName("Test1");
}
```

This works pretty well when I execute my tests in VS using ReSharper. The test-runner is able to seperate the tests that belong to `SubtractSegmentsTests` from those that belong to `SubtractSegmentsTests_With_Esri`.

Now I run those tests from within my Jenkins-Server:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" MySuT.dll --result:testresults/result.xml;format=nunit2
```

Here NUnit sorts all tests under the same node - the testclass - making it impossible to distinguish between `Test1` called from `SubtractSegmentsTests` and `Test1` from `SubtractSegmentsTests_With_Esri`.

Is there any way to get that level of aggregation on my CI-server as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A fast and dirty way is to have two different methods that you refer within the `TestCaseSource`.

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(ProvideTestCases1))]
public void SubtractSegmentsTests(IPolyline polyline, IPolyline toRemove, double tol, IGeometry expected)
{
    GeometryTools.SubtractSegments(polyline, toRemove, tol, null);
    AssertEqualPoints((IPointCollection) expected, (IPointCollection) polyline);
}
[TestCaseSource(nameof(ProvideTestCases2))]
public void SubtractSegmentsTests_With_Esri(IPolyline polyline, IPolyline toRemove, double tol, IGeometry expected)
{
    var actual = ((ITopologicalOperator)polyline).Difference(toRemove);
    AssertEqualPoints((IPointCollection)expected, (IPointCollection)actual);
}
```

Now create a third method that both `ProvideTestCases1` and `ProvideTestCases2` call with a parameter that incidicates where the call originated:

```
public IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ProvideTestCases1()
{
    return ProvideTestCases("Prefix1.");
}

public IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ProvideTestCases2()
{
    return ProvideTestCases("Prefix2.");
}

private IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ProvideTestCases(string prefix)
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(...).SetName(prefix + "Test1");
}
```

Now the name of the tests is concatenated, e.g. `Prefix1.Test1`.

That won´t aggregate your tests based on the test-method as within VS, but at least you can distinguish them.

EDIT: You won´t even need three methods. You can also use a single parameterized one and chose [the overload of `TestCaseSource`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) that provides arguments to the source:

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(ProvideTestCases), new object[] { "Prefix1" })]
public void SubtractSegmentsTests(IPolyline polyline, IPolyline toRemove, double tol, IGeometry expected) { ... }

[TestCaseSource(nameof(ProvideTestCases), new object[] { "Prefix2" })]
public void SubtractSegmentsTests(IPolyline polyline, IPolyline toRemove, double tol, IGeometry expected) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to restate what's probably already obvious to you, your two tests only have the same name because you have given them the same name. :-)

Some runners assume that names are unique. In order to deal with NUnit, which does not make that assumption, they usually add some prefix. The NUnit console runner is happy with tests that all have the same name, because they are actually identified by a (hidden) id. So NUnit console doesn't bother to display them differently, although it could if enough people asked.

However, NUnit also gives you the ability to make your own names unique when you set them. In this case, you only have to include "{m}" in the string that sets the name, and the name of the test method will be used in it's place.

For more info on setting names, see the docs at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Template-Based-Test-Naming

Comment: Cool, didn´t know this existed. If I´d known this eariler I would have considered to chose some different naming-convention for my tests.

Comment: Do you know if there´s a template-placeholder for the category as well? `{c}` refers to the test-class, unfortunately.